# How can I read 3GB of Gzip Compressed which goes more than 40GB after Extracting

Tags: python-3.x, large-files, compressed-files

I have been trying to read 3GB of gzip file. I have extracted it with gzip but after extracting it cannot even fit in 60GB of storage. So If I can't extract which is JSON so I can't read in bytes. I have found many questions all those were downloaded then extract into bytes and then read in bytes but here I can't even extract them.

So if it is possible to read while downloading in bytes? I have tried but the error says need to download the whole file.

Downloading Code :

```
default_path_download = '.'
def saveanddelete(download_url, name):
  with requests.get(download_url, headers=headersfordowlnoading, stream=True) as r:
      content_lenght = int(r.headers['Content-Length'])
      print(f"Download File Size : {round(content_lenght/1000000, 5)} MB")
      r.raise_for_status()
      with open(f"{default_path_download}/{name}", 'wb') as f:
          total_chunk_downloaded = 0
          chunk_size_to_get = 4096
          for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size_to_get):
              total_chunk_downloaded += len(chunk)
              if chunk:
                  f.write(chunk)
                  done = int(50 * total_chunk_downloaded / content_lenght)
                  print(f"Downloaded :  ", end='',flush=True)
                  print(f"{round(total_chunk_downloaded/1000000, 5)} MB [{'=' * done}{' ' * (50-done)}]\r", end='', flush=True)
                  break
          print("\n")
          print("Download Complete")
```

You can see the whole code on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pvPZVj1Qp2hmLzY2OXm_GM4nSz9O59Rl#scrollTo=i9zzD-lCvcxu)
I would like to other methods also if possible?
Thanks For Your Help!

Comment: You can use the pipe operator (`|`) to directly feed the decompressed output into the script (something like `gunzip -c archive.gz | python script.py`). There are streaming JSON decoder modules for python (for example, [`json-stream`](https://pypi.org/project/json-stream/)).

Comment: Also, python comes with a streaming [gzip module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html)

Comment: I have no idea to elevate it.